# Coordino - The requested URL /test/install/database-config was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Please help me how to resolve this error, I can't install it

- I changed “database_sample.php” to “database.php” in app/config folder,

app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then edit my Apache virtual host configuration, and changing

AllowOverride None

to

AllowOverride All

I don't know what to do anymore, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There should be three .htaccess files, not two. For example, if Coordino is located under /var/www/, they should be:

```
/var/www/.htaccess
/var/www/app/.htaccess
/var/www/app/webroot/.htaccess
```

You're probably missing the first one. Its contents should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the error 404 is still here - The requested URL /cordino/install/database-config was not found on this server. Yes, I have three .htaccess files and have </IfModule> at the end of the code, but in www/app/webroot/.htaccess default code in my case is RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? If not, type sudo a2enmod rewrite and then restart Apache.